# change active item in a card layout. ExtJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, extjs

I have a panel using the card layout as follows:

```
var cardpanel = new Ext.Panel(
{
    id: 'cardPanel',
    //title: 'Card Layout',
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'card',
    activeItem: 0,
    autoDestroy: false,
    bodyStyle: 'border-top:0px',
    defaults: {
        border: false
    },
    items: [mediaGrid, mappanel],
    tbar: [
        {
            id: 'card-media',
            text: 'Media',
            icon: '/img/silk/images.png',
            width: 50,
            handler: function () {
                //switch to media
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'card-map',
            text: 'Map',
            icon: '/img/silk/map.png',
            width: 50,
            handler: function () {
                //switch to map
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The commented parts are where i would like to implement the switch between the 2 panels in the card layout but im not sure how to do that. I've tried using setActiveItem but I was always either getting the setActiveItem is not a function or it it just didnt say anything.  How do i get it to switch panels?

Comment: How were you trying to call 'setActiveItem'?

Comment: i've tried setActiveItem(1), setActiveItem('1'), and setActiveItem('card-map').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call

```
this.layout.setActiveItem();
```

in handler and add

```
scope: cardpanel
```

under the handler definition.

Comment: Don't forget to pass in which item you want to set as the active item (e.g. `this.layout.setActiveItem(0)` or  `this.layout.setActiveItem('componentId')`)

Comment: i've tried both this.layout.setActiveItem(1) and this.layout.setActiveItem('card-map') and they both give me the same eror.

Answer (score 8):

You can only use `this` if you are in a handler for cardpanel.

```
cardpanel.layout.setActiveItem(0); // to switch to mediaGrid
cardpanel.layout.setActiveItem(1); // to switch to mappanel
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the "setActiveItem is not a function" because the object with which you are calling the method do not have the function. In short you are using the wrong object to call the setActiveItem method. You need to modify your code as:

```
{
            id: 'card-media',
            text: 'Media',
            icon: '/img/silk/images.png',
            width: 50,
            scope: this,
            handler: function () {
                this.layout.setActiveItem('card-map');
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'card-map',
            text: 'Map',
            icon: '/img/silk/map.png',
            width: 50,
            scope: this,
            handler: function () {
                this.layout.setActiveItem('card-media');
            }
        }
```