# Extjs : Redirecting to other page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Here is my code :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Results',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'form',
                style: 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    id: 'name',
                    style: 'width : 100px;'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'form',
                style: 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date',
                    id: 'date'

                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'form',
                style: 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    vtype: 'email',
                    fieldLabel: 'EmailId',
                    id: 'email'

                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'form',
                style: 'margin-top: 10px ',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'signup',
                    float: 'right',
                    handler: function() {

                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'rest/helloworld/',
                            disableCaching: false,
                            success: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('', 'success');
                                Window.Location.assign('abc.js');

                            },
                            failure: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('', 'failed');

                            },
                            params: {
                                name: Ext.getCmp('name').getValue(),
                                email: Ext.getCmp('email').getValue(),
                                date: Ext.getCmp('date').getValue()

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }]
            }

        ]

    });
});
```

Every thing is going great :

What I exactly need is to load another ExtJS page after success alert.

I tried `Window.Location.assign('abc.js')` but it is not working.

New to Extjs.

Please help

Comment: when you say a new Extjs page - you want to go to a different URL entirely, or you want to do something specific in Ext (like show a different panel). I doubt you really want to show the users the contents of abc.js, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: yeah it just read the file on the browser , how ever i want to load ui as per the code in file.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1** (Not Ext-JS related): It's not `Window.Location` , it's `window.location`

**Problem 2** (Ext-JS problem): `Ext.Msg.alert` dialog is asynchronous. The line `location.assign('www.google.com')` will run immediately after the dialog is displayed, not after it is dismissed

To wait until after the button pressed, you have to pass it a callback.

```
 Ext.Msg.alert('','success', function() {
     // Note that window is not necessary here, just location.assign will do
     window.location.assign('abc.js');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

or just:

```
location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

or even:

```
location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

However if you pass the name of a .js file as an argument it will just make the browser read and display it. Perhaps you need a card layout and put another view on top in your ExtJS application?

If you have a card layout your link will be "#" + itemId of the item(card) you want to display.

Comment: yeah it just read the file on the browser , how ever i want to load ui as per the code in file.

Comment: For this you don't need "window.location". You can put the component in this file on top. One way is by putting it in a card layout and saying it will become the active item. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383301/change-active-item-in-a-card-layout-extjs

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a misunderstanding of how the browser will executes JS. You don't want to redirect the browser to the new JS, but rather load the new JS on the current page. This can be accomplished by telling the browser to fetch the JS with a script tag:

```
var newJs = document.createElement('script');
newJs.type = "text/javascript";
newJs.src = 'abc.js';
document.body.appendChild(newJs);
```

More commonly you would have already loaded abc.js on your page and would have a method you need to invoke on it, or transition to a Ext Panel or something like that. For example:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        //this panel might be the contents of abc.js
        var abcPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title : 'Results',
            width : 600,
            height : 400,
            renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
            hidden: true
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title : 'Results',
            width : 600,
            height : 400,
            renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : 'form',
                style : 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Name',
                    id : 'name',
                    style : 'width : 100px;'
                } ]
            }, {
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : 'form',
                style : 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Date',
                    id : 'date'

                } ]
            }, {
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : 'form',
                style : 'width : 200px;margin-top: 10px ',
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'textfield',
                    vtype : 'email',
                    fieldLabel : 'EmailId',
                    id : 'email'

                } ]
            }, {
                xtype : 'container',
                layout : 'form',
                style : 'margin-top: 10px ',
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'button',
                    text : 'signup',
                    float : 'right',
                    handler : function() {
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            method : 'GET',
                            url : 'rest/helloworld/',
                            disableCaching : false,
                             success: function(){
                                 abcPanel.show();

                             },
                            failure: function(){
                                Ext.Msg.alert('','failed');

                            },
                            params : {
                                name : Ext.getCmp('name').getValue(),
                                email : Ext.getCmp('email').getValue(),
                                date : Ext.getCmp('date').getValue()

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } ]
            }

            ]

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: working great if all code exist in one file.... but if i keep abcPanel in other file .... it is givin error .... Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: You don't have document.body?